# How can I scrape, crawl, collect results from Google search with JSoup

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup, google-crawlers

It already worked a few weeks before, but now I am getting a page with the choice to accept or reject cookies.

My code:

```
String useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36";
    String urlbas = "https://www.google.com/search";
    String url = urlbas + "?q=Vienna&num=100&start=1";
    Map<String, String> cookies = null;
    try {
        // connect one time.                
        Connection con = Jsoup.connect(urlbas);
        Connection.Response res = con.execute();
        cookies = res.cookies();
        
        String ckey = "CONSENT";
        String cval = "YES+shp.gws-" + LocalDate.now().toString().replace("-", "") + "-0-RC2.en+FX+374";
        cookies.replace(ckey, cval);
        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .userAgent(useragent)
                .timeout(5000)
                .cookies(cookies)
                .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                
                .get();
        
        String pattern1 = ";url=";
        String pattern2 = "&amp;ved=";
        String txt = doc.body().html();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        // arres will contain the result
        arres = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            // adding to the result
            arres.add (m.group(1));

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

What the variable txt should contain is a list of the search results, but I get a request to accept cookies.

The solution does not need to include Jsoup, whatever works will be fine with me.

Comment: Scrapping Google search results is a violation of its ToS. While you can hack your way around the checks that are in place to prevent that, the system will eventually lock you out. If you want to make use of Google search in your app, consider using their [JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) instead. You get 100 search results per day free of charge.